# Trouble when generating a secretKey with Blowfish

Tags: java, security, cryptography, bouncycastle, blowfish

So I'm trying to get a secretKey for Blowfish using bouncycastle as this:

```
SecretKeyFactory factory =SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("Blowfish", "BC");
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: Blowfish for provider BC
  at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
  at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getInstance(JceSecurity.java:96)
  at javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(SecretKeyFactory.java:204)
  at Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

How do I solve this? (it also happens when I use "RC4" instead of "Blowfish", but it works with "DES" and "AES")

Answer (score 0):

Unlike asymmetric keys which have internal structure, you don't really need a factory for 'raw' secret (symmetric) keys, only those that use a derivation algorithm (PBE*, PBKDF2, etc). The standard (SunJCE) factories for DES and DESEDE do check/fix length and parity FWLIW, but the BC ones (plus AES beginning with 1.56) don't even do that. RC4 and Blowfish (among others) accept variable-length keys with no constraints on the bits, so there's not really anything the factory *could* do even if it were provided.

**Just put your key material in a `SecretKeySpec` and use that.** Unlike the other `*KeySpec` types, `SecretKeySpec` 'is-a' `SecretKey` (to be exact `implements` that interface) and can be used where a `SecretKey` or appropriate `Key` is needed, particularly in `Cipher.init(mode, key ...)`

---

If you really want to *generate* a key, not use/convert an existing one, you don't want a factory anyway. In spite of the name, factories only convert, they don't create. To generate a key you either need a `KeyGenerator` (or for asymmetric `KeyPairGenerator`) and those DO exist for RC4 (aka ARC4) and BLOWFISH in BC, and also in standard SunJCE but using the names ARCFOUR and BLOWFISH; or (for raw symmetric) just use `SecureRandom` to generate the correct number of bytes, and use that.